# Finding $x,y$ for a given $p,q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following equation:

$px + qy = 1$

$p,q$ are coprime integers and $x,y$ are integers. Given a specific pair of $p,q$, I want to find a pair of integers $x,y$.

It was quite easy to prove that for any given $p,q$, there are infinitely many pairs of $x,y$.

One can also see that if $x_1, y_1$ works, $x_1 + nq, y_1 - np$ also works for any integer $n$. I have been racking my brains for weeks now, but I can't seem to find a way to find $x,y$ without bruteforce.

P.S: This is a problem I came up with by myself, so I don't know what (if any) textbook I could refer to.

Comment: You may wish to look up Bezout's Theorem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: That is one of the applications of the Euclidean algorithm, Bézout's identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#B%C3%A9zout's_identity

Comment: Nice! But at least the Wikipedia article does not seem to talk about the form $x$ and $y$ takes.

Comment: The article explains the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Mathematics is so universal and timeless.  You and Euclid 1000's of years apart pondering the same question.

Comment: @tkf: Euclid is much older. Malik Ayaz lived approximately 1000 years ago.